# Library that would work on Mac, PC and that can also be ported on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, cross-platform, desktop-application

I'm going to be building a library for processing and generating SyncML messages (SyncML = XML protocol for syncing contacts and calendars), and I'd like to be able to port and use this library on as many devices as possible (Mac, PC, iPhone, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Phone 7), mostly because the logic is going to be the same, and I don't want to spend time on re-building it as a native library for each platform.

My question is: what technologies and programming languages should I look into for getting this done? Java, C and C++ spring to mind, and also a colleague has suggested Lua. I'd like to get SO's opinion on this before I seriously start working on it.

My background is mainly C#/.NET, Objective-C, and some Java.

Any information is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?  Java has a runtime environment for Mac, PC, Linux, Android, Blackberry, and Windows Mobile.  Unfortunately the most popular option, iPhone, has a propriatary coding platform and probably can't run java.

Java has done the hard work for you in writing a cross-platform runtime environment.  Be careful which version of the Java platform you use though, some mobile devices may not support the newest SE yet.

With an objective-c and C# .NET background, Java should be childs play for you to pick up.